# I want to play music in my Android game as well as analyse the sound data. Using Unity C#

Tags: c#, android, audio, unity-game-engine

This may be a bit complex but I'll try to break it down. I'm building an Android game using the Unity 5 engine and C# scripts. I have my basic elements and the next and hardest step in my project is to do the following:

I need to play in the background music stored on the user phone determined at runtime.
I want to also read the sound data of this file to manipulate gameplay (based on the song file).

The problem I'm encountering is that the music feature of Unity itself is limited to music I put into the Assets as opposed to figured at runtime from the Android music directory. Using a simplified version of the code found on 
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/652919/music-player-get-songs-from-directory.html
I can get the music to play from Assets on my computer when run but the music won't play on my phone from the included Assets and if I can figure that out, I'm not sure it will even work with an Android filepath.

Is there a better way to do this or is the above link the best start and why doesn't the sound play from my phone? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to get the data from a custom folder on their phone, then you will need to read the audio file's bytes and cache to disk. You can then create an audio clip and play it as you usually would. I can't help you with the android file system, but a quick google will help you with the directory format.

The problem with this is it will be slow as mentioned in the source post from Unity Answers.

```
             byte[] rawData = byte[];
         string tempFile = Application.persistentDataPath + "/bytes.mp3";
         System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tempFile, rawData);

         WWW loader = new WWW("file://" + tempFile);
         yield return loader;
         if(!System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(loader.error))
             Debug.LogError(loader.error);

         AudioClip s1 = loader.GetAudioClip(false, false, AudioType.MPEG);
                     //or
         AudioClip s2 = loader.audioClip;
```

SOURCE: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/686240/audioclip-oggmp3-loaded-from-byte-array.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at that when I get down to coding again. The game I'm trying to make isn't too system intensive altogether and most of the performance draw will come from this music engine itself so I think I can manage this performance set back and this looks promising. I'll be sure to let you know if this solves my problem. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Good luck dude, I'd love to know if this works and what the performance difference really is.